# Which software can help me execute commands on a remote Windows machine without opening the command prompt on the remote machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-access

The title says everything. I am looking for a TeamViewer like software which allows me to run commands on the remote machine without needing to start command prompt on the remote machine.

I am not looking to connect to a server, I am looking to connect to other users over the internet as quickly and easily as AnyDesk/TeamViewer.

Comment: If you don't want to start a command prompt on the remote machine outside of a Windows domain you need something like an ssh server. Check out OpenSSH.

Comment: All versions of Windows are able to run commands on all other copies of Windows, using Named Pipes. Only security configuration and firewalls prevent you from doing so.